# Constructor Exception and Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c++

I was wondering if an object is dynamically allocated and the constructor throws an exception, does the object still need to be deleted ?

```
class Doom
{
public:

   Doom() { throw 0; }

private:

   int pad;

};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // memory is allocated for Doom but construction fails
        // is the memory deallocated if construction fails here ?
        Doom* doom = new Doom(); 
    }
    catch(int ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`. Never think about deleting memory or having leaks again.

Comment: @Dave: Using `unique_ptr` isn't enough - `foo(unique_ptr(new bar()), unique_ptr(new bar()))`; can still leak. You need `make_unique`/`make_shared`.

Comment: @JoeGauterin: Care to elaborate more about how that would leak ? Edit: ah i think i see it now, new bar() is called, then the other new bar() is called before the unique_ptr is constructed for the other bar but this one throws an exception leaving the previous one leaked.

Comment: This Herb Sutter article explains in depth - http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's nothing to delete, because the object never got constructed. The compiler will take care of freeing the memory that was allocated.